# Http request is sending 2 times through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My AJAX code is as follows:

```
data = new FormData();
   //  data="";
    paths = "";


    // Create a new HTTP requests, Form data item (data we will send to the server) and an empty string for the file paths.
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


    // Set how to handle the response text from the server
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
        //console.debug(xhr.responseText);
     //  console.log("success"+xhr.responseText);

    try{
      console.log($.parseJSON(xhr.responseText));

       var data=$.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

      if(data.success=="yes"){

          projectCounter++;            
          var projectName=$.parseJSON(data.arguments);
          console.log(projectName.projectName);

          console.log('update table');

          if(projectCounter==2){

              UploadComplete(projectName.projectName);

          }


      }

     } 
     catch(e){}

    };

    // Loop through the file list
    for (var i in files){
        // Append the current file path to the paths variable (delimited by tripple hash signs - ###)
        paths += files[i].webkitRelativePath+"###";
        // Append current file to our FormData with the index of i
        data.append(i, files[i]);
    };
    // Append the paths variable to our FormData to be sent to the server
    // Currently, As far as I know, HTTP requests do not natively carry the path data
    // So we must add it to the request manually.
    data.append('paths', paths);
    // console.log(paths);   
    // Open and send HHTP requests to upload.php
    xhr.open('POST', "upload.php", true);
     console.log(data);   

    xhr.send(this.data);
```

the issue i am facing is that it is sending http request 2 times. I am recieving Http response 2 times. I have written console.log("update Table") and it is showing 2 times. I am very confused why i am recieving 2 times Http response instead of the fact that i am sending only 1 request?

Comment: is it possible to show the context of which this code runs?

Comment: melc it sends request to upload.php which uploads data upload.php script is running fine. i have checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving multiple readyState events in the course of a request. What you want here is to only be notified when the request completes.

Extend your handler with this:

```
if(xhr.readyState === 4  //ready) {

}
```

UPDATE:
The original problem was solved with simple equality check (untyped), which leads to the assumption that in some browsers the readyState is a `string typed field` containing a `number`.

```
if(xhr.readyState == 4  //ready) {

}
```

Comment: sir xhr.readyState===4 is not working it is not showing anything

Comment: what do you see if you write console.log(xhr.readyState) - remove the if() clause so that you are invoked for each readyState change...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't testing the `readyState` in your `onreadystatechange` handler. The function will fire every time the state changes. It is usual to abort the function (by returning) when the readyState isn't *done*.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
    if (this.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: @MuneemHabib — For the reasons described in the paragraph before the code.

Comment: sir this.readystate!==4 and i alert some text it is called almost 4 times

Comment: It shouldn't do. The readystate function will fire multiple times (4 is quite common) but it should only change to state 4 once so it shouldn't get past that return statement more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not checking the readyState value of the xhr.
The onreadystatechange callback code should be wrapped with an if statement:

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    // your code here...
}
```

Only when the readyState is 4, the request is actually done.

Regards,
Udi

Comment: sir xhr.readyState === 4 is not working it is not showinf anyhting